# UILabel textColor doesn't set properly in iOS 4.3

Tags: ios, uilabel, ios4

While working with iOS 5.1 Simulator app felt great, but after testing it on iOS 4.3 Simulator some sort of unintelligible issue appeared:

I use custom UITableViewCell for UITableView, and it has few UILabels and one UITextView. The problem is that textColor property seems not to work at all - all the text on my labels remain being invisible despite the background is shown and NSLog prints right text. I tried changing textColor value both in IB and programmatically but neither helped.

What about UITextView - it's ok. I guess, I could substitute all the labels with textViews, but it's not the good way of programming, is it?

I'll be thankful no end for any kind of your help because it just blows my mind away!

**Update (source code added)**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FeedItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[FeedItemCell cellID]];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [FeedItemCell cell];
    }

    NSIndexPath *selectedPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (selectedPath && (indexPath.row == selectedPath.row) ) {
        [self selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    [cell fillWithContents:[feedItemsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

//---
@implementation FeedItemCell 

- (void)fillWithNewsItemContents:(FeedItem *)feedItem {
    self.nameLabel.text = [feedItem.creator fullName];
    self.dateLabel.text = [TimeFormatter newsTimeWithDate:feedItem.postedDate];
    self.detailTextView.text = [FeedItemCell detailTextViewStringFromFeedItem:feedItem];
    self.commentLabel.text = [self _commentsTitleWithNews:feedItem];
    self.avatarImageView.image = [feedItem.creator avatar];
}
```

All the `UILabel`s are defined in `xib`-file
[image]

Comment: I suppose this will be some stupid mistake from your part. Could you show us the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I found the solution. For some reason `UILabel` doesn't support Helvetica Neue font in iOS 4.3 (in spite of fact that `UITextView` does).
I just noted it adding other test `UILabel`s and, after success, trying to find difference between new and old ones.

Thus now it takes only to choose another suitable font :)

Thank you all very much and sorry for troubling without worth reason.

Comment: iOS4.3 and less is supporting Helvetice Neue, it just only support the Bold, Bold Italic, Italic and the normal form. Not the thin, Medium, light and stuff like that.
in iOS5 and up the default label font is Helvetice Neue Light what not exist in pre iOS5, and that was the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is very weird. But i will suggest you to test on actual iOS 4.3 and 5.1 device. Simulators are 95% accurate not 100 %. So you should do a sanity check on device.

Answer (score 0):

It would be really great to see your code – particularly, I'd like to see:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Or wherever else you allocate, instantiate and add as a subview these misbehaving `UILabel`s.  But I can make a couple guesses as to what might be going wrong:

- You might be trying to set elements of the `UILabel` before it is properly allocated or instantiated.  This can happen if, for example, you call:

  ```
  [myLabel setText:@"Hello"];
  ```

  before you call:

  ```
  UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
  ```

  If you do something like that, it will compile fine and fail silently at runtime.
- You might be forgetting to add the label to the proper `UIView` – in a `UITableViewCell`, the contents are should typically be added as subviews of the cell's `contentView` property:

  ```
  [[myCell contentView] addSubview:myLabel];
  ```

There are some other things that could be happening, but I'd rather see the code you're using before making any blind guesses.  I'll update my answer then.